# Unable to reach binding.pry

Tags: ruby, debugging, binding.pry

Trying to use `binding.pry` works until the `emoticons_hash.each`
Trying to use it inside of `.each` or after it will not trigger it. It also doesn't work within other methods of this program, even with a `puts "hello"` after it.

```
require 'pry'
require 'yaml'
def load_library(filepath)
  emoticons_hash = YAML.load_file (filepath)
  puts emoticons_hash.inspect

  language_hash = {}
  emoticons_hash.each do |emoticon|
   language_hash[emoticon] = emoticons_hash[emoticon].value
   binding.pry
  end
  binding.pry
  puts "hello"
end

def english
     binding.pry
      puts "hello"
    end
```

Comment: Are you definitely calling these methods (`english` and `load_library`)?

Answer (score 0):

There's something in your `emoticons_hash` variable? If yes, it responds to `.each` method?

I think your `binding.pry` are not reaching this way because one of these two problems.